# Is there a jira plugin for managing daily performance/bug testing or statistics?

Tags: project-management, jira, jira-plugin

At work we thought it would be nice to track our performance statistics on a daily basis with Jira. We already have an automated testing suite, but ideally we could link this to Jira ticket spanning a project, and every day the automated results would be added to the top level ticket info, and a comment or subtask would be created with detailed stats and detailed performance analysis by an engineer.

Does anything like this exist, or would this require writing an actual jira plugin?

Comment: Do you have additional software in use? Like a build server for automatic unit tests, or some other software? That may help to find a solution ...

Comment: we're running hudson and it's integrated with jira I think, plus some other stuff. I'm just curious as to what's out there without actually writing a hudson/jenkins plugin to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking here about some unusual usage of JIRA. Normally, you have a lot of tickets to a project, and not 1 ticket "spanning a project". Here are some hints what could be available (depending on the other software your are using):

- If you use a build environment like Hudson or Jenkins, there are plugins available to link the fixed issues to the build where the fixes were made. See ["Jenkins JIRA Plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) for some more information. So if you have a nightly build (once a day), Jenkins will give you a list of JIRA tickets that were worked on.
- JIRA itself has a lot of charts that may be worth looking at. So e.g. the "Created vs. Resolved Chart" shows you the tickets that were created anew and were solved on a daily, weekly or monthly basis.
- Eventually, the data you search for is available as a gadget (see the [documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Introduction+to+Atlassian+Gadgets+and+Dashboards)). Then you can add that information to your dashboard by using the normal mechanisms of JIRA.

None of the tips above does exactly what you want to get ...

Comment: It's a good answer- I was wondering what was out there that was similar to this. JIRA dashboard + custom Jenkins plugin sounds like the solution.